blender 4.2 viewport looks very off for low poly models
When I load models into blender 4.2 they look very washed out with no detail which is making it difficult to work on.
Below are some examples with default settings of both blender 4.2 and blender 3.6.9
Here is an example of an object in 4.2

While this is what previous versions of blender looked like.

I understand that the lighting and such has been updated but I wouldn't think this is normal. I have tried all different types of matcap and other lighting settings but nothing seems to be fixing this (problem).
any insight would be helpful

You say "you don't think this is normal" but in fact that's exactly what it is. They completely overhauled the way AutoSmooth, sharp edges, split normals etc works in between those two versions. I would first try Clear Custom Split Normal Data in the Object Data > Geometry Data properties panel. Then add a Smooth By Angle modifier to the object. I think that should do it.

I doubt there is any data to clear by the looks of it, though I could be wrong. But instead of adding the modifier manually, you can also just right click > Shade Auto Smooth.

Thank you guys, This really helped. I understand this was the way their lighting was supposed to work. The suggestion by Lauloque to right click and shade auto smooth worked like a charm. I appreciate the assistance.

@Jamie It has nothing to do with lighting. It's about smoothing normals and the resulting shading (shading ≠ lighting).
